# Load Multiple Files from maxcdn at once

Tags: html, css, performance, cdn

I am using bootstrap and font-awesome from max cdn like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

as you can see it sending two different request for two different files is there any way to load these two files in one request

Comment: @SaurabhMistry  I don't want to copy content of files locally I want to keep in maxcdn for caching benefit and request these two files at once 

like Google font API below I am loading two font at once 
```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans|Supermercado+One" rel="stylesheet">
``` 
is there any way to load two files at once like above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jsdelivr instead and Combine multiple files: https://www.jsdelivr.com/features

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/combine/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css,npm/font-awesome@4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```